# IIF in microsoft report builder

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I need to insert an IIF into the following expression in micorsoft report builder, and I keep getting an error.  I want it to say if >1,1,""

=Round((Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) * 100,0) & "% (" & Round(((Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) - Fields!peer_group.Value) * 100,0) & "%)"

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you tried but this should work:

```
=IIF(Round((Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) * 100,0) > 1,
    100, 
    Round((Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) * 100,0)) & 
"% (" & Round(((Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) - Fields!peer_group.Value) * 100,0) & "%)"
```

I think you'd be better using FORMATPERCENT to format your number with a set number of decimal places and adding the percent sign.

```
=FORMATPERCENT(
    IIF(
        (Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) * 100 > 1, 
            1, 
            (Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) * 100
        )
    , 0) & " ("
 FORMATPERCENT(((Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) - Fields!peer_group.Value) * 100, 0) & ")"
```

Comment: Better still would be to not do any formatting in the expression and just use `"p0"` in the format property of the textbox. `"p0"` would show the value `0.1234` as `12%`, something like `"p2"` would show the same with 2 decimal places, i.e. `12.34%`

Comment: Showing as a percent isn't the problem.  I downloaded data from surveys, and entered in responses.  It's where the two add up to more than 100 (101%).  I want it to perform if greater than 1 (100%), then 1, else what it should be.

Comment: Using the following returned all values of 1 
  =IIF(Round((Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) * 100,0)>1,1,"") & "% (" & Round(((Fields!percent_excellent.Value + Fields!percent_good.Value) - Fields!peer_group.Value) * 100,0) & "%)"

Comment: @AlanSchofield - He couldn't use the Text Box FORMAT property in this case - there's two different values in one text box (i.e. `75% (12%)`).

Comment: @Stasia - you don't show you values for `percent_excellent` and `percent_excellent`. I'm thinking maybe you SHOULDN'T be multiplying them by 100.

Comment: The formula without the if stmt works perfect, data validated.  it's when the if is added that there is an issue.  I'm trying to eliminate the 101%'s

Comment: @Stasia - I think you just need to change the `* 100 > 1` to `* 100 > 100` in the IIF